# How to test multiple RouteBuilders in Apache Camel

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-camel

I want to test multiple camel RouteBuilder in a single unit test
what I have:

Custom camel processor that changes state

```
public class MyProcessor implements Processor {
   MyState state;
   public MyProcessor(MyState state) {this.state = state;}

   @Override
   public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
   state.setState(state.getState() + 5);
   }}
```

Two simple RouteBuilders: first routes messages from "direct:start" to "direct:endroute1" second pick up messages from "direct:endroute1" and routes somewhere "mock:endroute2"

```
public class MyRouteBuilder1 extends RouteBuilder {
    MyState state;
    public MyRouteBuilder1(MyState state) {this.state = state;}

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:start").process(new MyProcessor(state)).to("direct:endroute1");
    }}

public class MyRouteBuilder2 extends RouteBuilder {
    MyState state;
    public MyRouteBuilder2(MyState state) {this.state = state;}

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:endroute1").process(new MyProcessor(state)).to("mock:endroute2");
    }}
```

Writing unit test for a single route builder is straightforward:

```
public class MyTest extends CamelTestSupport {
    MyState state = new MyStateImpl();

    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:result")
    protected MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

    @Test
    public void testSingleRoute() throws Exception {
        resultEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
        template.sendBody("direct:start", new Object());
        assertTrue(state.getState() == 5);
        resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
     return new MyRouteBuilder1(state) {
            public void configure() throws Exception{
               super.configure();
               from("direct:endroute1").to("mock:result");
           }
     };
 }
}
```

What I really want to do is somehow to override `CamelTestSupport.createRouteBuilder` that will test whole chain of message processing from `direct:start` to `mock:endroute2`. As a result `state.getState()` should be 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can just add multiple RouteBuilders to the context using the `context.addRoutes(RouteBuilder)` API

see this unit test for an example:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/builder/AddRoutesAtRuntimeTest.java

Answer (score 8):

Try to override method:

```
protected RouteBuilder[] createRouteBuilders() {...}
```

from CamelTestSupport. It's available since version 2.17

Answer (score 0):

You could use one RouteBuilder [including](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/builder/RouteBuilder.html#includeRoutes%28org.apache.camel.RoutesBuilder%29) the routes of multiple other RouteBuilders.