# Query regarding unit testing of camel multiple routes within the same class

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-camel

I'm having issues unit testing multiple camel routes within the same class.I have a class which contains several route definitions. e.g. as below:

```
public class A extends RouteBuilder{
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        method1();
        method2();
        method3();
        ...
    }
    private void method1() {
        // contains route definitions
        final RouteDefinition route = from("direcct:");
        route.id("ID1");
        route.setHeader("",simple(""));
        route.to("direct:B");
        route.end();
    }
// similarly other methods
}
```

i want to unit test each method. so have extended CamelTestSupport. can't override the methods in configure when creating routebuilder since the method are private.
this is what i am doing currently

```
public class A extends CamelTestSupport {
    private A route;
    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        route = new A();
//can't use below configure since methods are private
    //@Override public void configure() throws Exception {
    //  method1();
    //}

        //logic for mocking and setting endpoints using mockito
        
        return route;
    }
@Test
public void method1_test() throws Exception {
}
}
```

I can test one method while commenting others(camelcontext loads and starts all the routes in a class).If i don't comment the test fails.
Also for testing other methods within the same test class i cant use the same createRoutebuilder.So below are the questions:

1. How will i test other methods within the same test class
2. Is there a way to start and stop routeid so i can test only those routes(tries startroute method but since all the routes are already started it doesn't do anything)
3. Is there any workaround so that individual methods can be tested
   Using camel 3.6, spring boot2 and junit 5

Comment: for the auto startup, this could help: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/configuring-route-startup-ordering-and-autostartup.html

Comment: You want to keep route definitions 1, 2 and 3 separate, and test them separately? There is a good linked question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295316/how-to-test-multiple-routebuilders-in-apache-camel?rq=1

Comment: thanks for the answer. Yes want to test the methods seperately but within the same test class say for example for class A test i will create one test class with three junit test case. As you can see when i am extending cameltestsupport  i can override createroutebuilder once but will not work for other methods

Comment: route definitions are already defined in one class.each method has one route definition. How will i test those?

Comment: OK, can you move the route definitions into separate `RouteBuilder` classes? I'd say that's the most typical way to modularise a Camel app, 1 RouteBuilder for each set of routes. What's the need for them to be in the same class?

Comment: agreed but thats the way its written and i cant change those.the class serves a particular functionality which consist of sequence of steps divided into routes.each route definition serves a particular purpose

Comment: Hi, Apurava! Given the "limitations" you've commented about above, it seems to me that you'd have to make use of interceptors in your Unit Test Context. PS.: I'm used to modularizing routes and externalize components declaration to make routes "more testable", using the mock component when in a test context / environment to write the asserts, divert routing etc.